# Sum up a column from a specific row down

Tags: excel, excel-formula

It seem simple but I cannot find a way to define a range that goes up to the end of the column in an Excel formula.

For instance I can use this equation SUM(C:C) to sum all number found on the column C. However, given that the top of the page has titles and column headers, I would like to start my range at line 6. I thought SUM(C6:C) would do it but it does not work in Excel.

This is required so my SUM is always right no matter how many lines of data I add to my document in the future.

Thanks.

Comment: If all that is above the C6 is text anyways, text will not be summed with the rest of the column as the values need to be numeric.

Comment: The thing is that I cannot guaranty what will be the content above because the file may be used by different people and even I may forget over time that I cannot put numbers above.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
=Sum(C:C)-Sum(C1:C5)
```

Sum everything then remove the sum of the values in the cells you don't want, no Volatile Offset's, Indirect's, or Array's needed.

Just for fun if you don't like that method you could also use:

```
=SUM($C$6:INDEX($C:$C,MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,$C:$C))
```

The above formula will Sum only from C6 through the last cell in C:C where a match of a number is found. This is also non-volatile, but I believe more costly and sloppy. Just added it in case you'd prefer this anyways.

If you would like to do function like CountA for text using the last text value in a column you could use.

```
=COUNTIF(C6:INDEX($C:$C,MATCH(REPT("Z",255),$C:$C)),"T")
```

you could also use other combinations like:

```
=Sum($C$6:$C$65536)
```

or

```
=CountIF($C$6:$C$65536,"T")
```

The above would do what you ask in Excel 2003 and lower

```
=Sum($C$6:$C$1048576)
```

or

```
=CountIF($C$6:$C$1048576,"T")
```

Would both work for Excel 2007+

All above functions would simply ignore all the blank values under the last value.

Comment: It would work for a SUM but I'm not sure about other functions that use ranges. For example I need to count the rows of a column that contain text with =COUNTIF(C:C,"T"). But thinking about it your method of removing the COUNTIF(C1:C5,"T") for the first lines would work but I just don't feel like it is a clean way to do it.

Comment: @jmbouffard  That is why I both answered your original question and added a second option. Which as far as I know is the ONLY Non-Volatile and Non-Array way to get the last cell.

Comment: Thanks for proposing the second option but this will get the range only from the first cell to the last cell that contains a number. So it is not useful with a set of text data as in the example of my previous comment.

Comment: But I agree my question was not specific enough so I will wait for some time to see if there are any other proposals and accept your answer otherwise.

Comment: I have updated my answer, if you require more information or assistance, please start a new question that is more specific to what exactly you are actually looking for.

Comment: The first formula `=Sum(C:C)-Sum(C1:C5)` creates a circular reference and does not work. Puting this formula in cell `C6` works with the contents of cell `C6` when you want to work out what cell `C6` should be.  Changing the subtraction section does the same.  That idea cannot be used.

Answer (score 8):

You all seem to love complication. Just click on column(to select entire column), press and hold CTRL and click on cells that you want to exclude(C1 to C5 in you case). Now you have selected entire column C (right to the end of sheet) without starting cells. All you have to do now is to rightclick and "Define Name" for your selection(ex. asdf ). In formula you use  SUM(asdf).  And now you're done. Good luck

Allways find the easyest way ;)

Comment: You can even insert the SUM on top in the same column without getting cyclic error

Comment: If you want to add something to your answer, you should edit it. On SO, it is encouraged to improve questions and answers by editing them.

Comment: The "New Name" dialog shows that the named range will actually be `=Sheet1!$C$6:$C$1048576`. So the constant of maximum number of rows is used.

Comment: That would not work.  That would generate `=SUM(C:C,C1:C5)`

Answer (score 7):

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/284953/excel-how-do-i-reference-an-entire-row-except-for-a-couple-of-cells) seems like the easiest (but not most robust) way to me.  Simply compute the sum from row 6 to the maximum allowed row number, as specified by Excel.  According to this [site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#ID0EBABAAA=Newer_versions), the maximum is currently 1048576, so the following should work for you:

```
=sum(c6:c1048576)
```

For more robust solutions, see the other answers.

Comment: This is the most efficient and will work in Excel 2007 and later. Excel 2003 would need `=SUM(C6:C655366)` as the maximum number of possible rows is lower.

Comment: @ChrisRogers you probably mean `=SUM(C6:65536)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using OFFSET(), which is a volatile function that recalculates everytime a cell is changed, then this is a good solution that is both dynamic and reusable:

```
=OFFSET($COL:$COL, ROW(), 1, 1048576 - ROW(), 1)
```

where $COL is the letter of the column you are going to operate upon, and ROW() is the row function that dynamically selects the same row as the cell containing this formula. You could also replace the ROW() function with a static number ($ROW).

```
=OFFSET($COL:$COL, $ROW, 1, 1048576 - $ROW, 1)
```

You could further clean up the formula by defining a named constant for the 1048576 as 'maxRows'. This can be done in the 'Define Name' menu of the Formulas tab.

```
=OFFSET($COL:$COL, $ROW, 1, maxRows - $ROW, 1)
```

A quick example: to Sum from C6 to the end of column C, you could do:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(C:C, 6, 1, maxRows - 6, 1))
```

or
    =SUM(OFFSET(C:C, ROW(), 1, maxRows - ROW(),1))

Answer (score 0):

Something like this worked for me (references columns C and D from the row 8 till the end of the columns, in Excel 2013 if relevant):

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(D$8), COLUMN())&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS($C:$C), COLUMN())),INDIRECT("C$8:C"&ROWS($C:$C)),$C$2)
```